# Filter on Custom Angular JS Directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I know how to use filter on existing directives:

```
<div multiple 
    ng-repeat="item in items | filter:searchTerm"></div>
```

I wanted to use filter on a custom directive that I have created.
How do I make the filter work on my custom directives?

```
<div multiple 
    my-custom-repeat="item in items | filter:searchTerm"></div>
```

For eg: http://plnkr.co/edit/1LeagzIdpwoTctMGZUfT?p=preview

The filter in the above plunk doesn't work. Whats the best way to get it to work?

Comment: What does your directive look like? Typically a directive attribute doesn't supplant `ng-repeat`.

Comment: I am not replicating ng-repeat but I have created a directive which accepts a collection/array. I want to filter that collection/array using filters

Comment: Your repeat collection should be modified in your controller, not in a directive. You'd then apply the filter as normal.

Comment: Or perhaps you can just use an expression: my-custom-repeat="{{items|myFilter}}"

Comment: I would tend to agree with @isherwood. Unless you have some complex requirement for a component that is going to get used A LOT, and there is significant incentive to get filter expressions working, it would be best just to handle to filtering in your controller code. That said, as I recall the ui-bootstrap library had a custom version of filter expressions for the typehead directive. You could check that.

Comment: Apologies but I don't understand. I have attached a plunk in my question. Would you be able to show me where the issue is?

Comment: I'm not sure what your directive is intended to do. Here's a dramatically simplified version of your example that seems to have the same functionality. Please explain. http://plnkr.co/edit/jotl1HH3dVW19UP3aujp?p=preview

Comment: (Actually, the search filter doesn't work in your original example.)

Comment: I started the question by saying, I know how to use the filter in existing directives like ng-repeat. What I am trying to understand is how to I make them work for my custom directives. I have tried to simulate ng-repeat in the above plunk. But the filter doesn't work as you pointed out before. I want to find out a way to make it work.

Comment: If you look at my code, you will see that in the transclude function in script.js, I am parsing the string that the user passes. In this case it is "hunter in bountyHunters | filter:searchTerm". Is there a way that I can make the filter work other than writing my own filter logic? Hopefully this clears my question.